# How to create lexical rules with optional part in ANTLR4

Tags: grammar, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I am trying to create a grammar to define a Boolean literal using ANTLR4. It can take the form of either "BOOL#TRUE", or just "TRUE".

if I define it as a lexical rule like this:

```
Bool_Literal    : ( 'BOOL' '#' )? ( 'FALSE' | 'TRUE' );
```

Antlr cannot match the input:

```
isHigh := FALSE;
```

the error is "mismatched input 'FALSE' expecting Bool_Literal".

But if I change it to a grammar rule:

```
bool_literal    : ( 'BOOL' '#' )? ( 'FALSE' | 'TRUE' );
```

it can correctly pick up either "BOOL#FALSE" or just "FALSE".

It seems that the lexical rule cannot detect a token which starts with an optional part, anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Wayne

Here is my grammar:

---

```
grammar TT;

pou
  : assignment +  
  ;

assignment  : Identifier ':=' expression ';' ;  
expression  : primary_expr ;  
primary_expr    : Bool_Literal;   

//bool_literal          : ( 'BOOL' '#' )? ( 'FALSE' | 'TRUE' );

 // lexical   
fragment Letter         : [a-zA-Z]|'_' ;  
fragment Digit          : [0-9];  
fragment Bit            : [0-1];  
fragment Octal_Digit    : [0-7];  
fragment Hex_Digit      : [0-9a-fA-F];  

Identifier          : Letter (Letter|Digit)*;  

Bool_Literal            : ( 'BOOL' '#' )? ( 'FALSE' | 'TRUE' );  

WS      : [ \n\r\t]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;  
Comment     :   '//' .*? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN); // channel COMMENTS)   //     
EOL         : '\n';
```

---

my test input:

```
isLow := BOOL#TRUE;  
isLow2 := BOOL#FALSE;  
isHigh := FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antlr, like most lexical scanner generators, gives precedence to the first rule which matches a token, in the case that the longest possible token could be matched by two or more rules.

In your grammar, `TRUE` and `FALSE` could be matched either as identifiers or as boolean literals. Since the identifier rule comes earlier in the grammar, it will win and thus `FALSE` will be an identifier.

So put the `Bool_literal` rule where the `bool_literal` rule appears -- or at least before the `identifier` rule -- and then it will win instead.

See the question "Why are my keywords being treated as identifiers?" in [this Antlr4 FAQ](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/faq/lexical.md).

Comment: it works after I move up the Bool_Literal rule. Thanks!